# How to Fix: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: description, end_time, id, start_time, title Django Error

Tags: python, django, database, forms, view

Hi guys I'm a beginner to Django and I'm trying to implement a login system into my django planner.

The error:

FieldError at /login_user/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: description, end_time, id, start_time, title

I've tried adding the user field into my event model on model.py and migrating it but it just makes the whole application crash.

---

## views.py

```
def event(request, event_id=None):
    instance = Event()
    if event_id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)
    else:
        instance = Event()

    form = EventForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:calendar'))
    return render(request, 'cal/event.html', {'form': form})

def login_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                events = Event.objects.filter(user=request.user)
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'cal/calendar.html', {'calendar': calendar})
            else:
                return render(request, 'cal/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'cal/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
    return render(request, 'cal/login.html')
```

---

## forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password',]
```

---

## models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('cal:event_edit', args=(self.id,))
        return f'<a href="{url}"> {self.title} </a>'
```

---

## calendar.html

```
{% extends 'cal/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Calendar
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="btn btn-info left" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}?{{ prev_month }}"> Previous Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}?{{ next_month }}"> Next Month </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="{% url 'cal:event_new' %}"> New Event </a>
</div>

{{ calendar }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

## login.html

```
{% extends 'cal/base_visitor.html' %}
{% block title %}Log In{% endblock %}
{% block login_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>Log In</h3>
                    {% if error_message %}
                        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{% url 'cal:login_user'%}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id_username">
                                Username:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id_password">
                                Password:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="id_password" maxlength="30" name="password" type="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'cal:register' %}">Click here</a> to register.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

In your view you are filtering Event objects with the keyword user, but your event model has no field called user. If you want your event associated with a user you can add a foreignkey to your Event model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('cal:event_edit', args=(self.id,))
        return f'<a href="{url}"> {self.title} </a>'
```

Or, in your view, you can simply filter your Event objects by another keyword the choices for which your error gave you, and which are just the fields you specified in your model. So in your view you could do this:

```
def login_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                events = Event.objects.filter(title='Title you want to filter by') # This line seems to be the source of your error. You just need to filter by a keyword that exists in your model.
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'cal/calendar.html', {'calendar': calendar})
            else:
                return render(request, 'cal/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'cal/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
    return render(request, 'cal/login.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your models.py you missed adding a relationship for your user table. add **user** and do a

python manage.py makemigrations myapp

python manage.py migrate myapp

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def get_html_url(self):
        url = reverse('cal:event_edit', args=(self.id,))
        return f'<a href="{url}"> {self.title} </a>'
```